# No module named 'pygame' Модуль не импортируется

Tags: python, windows, pygame

Я пишу на Python через Pygame на Windows 10, я установил его, vscode его видит но когда я запускаю код выходит ошибка No module named 'pygame'. Он установлен, в файлах python есть, в списке установленных библиотек тоже есть, итерпритатор его видит, но программа с pygame не запускается.

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stacktuts.com/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-pygame-in-python#:~:text=The%20ImportError%3A%20No%20module%20named,even%20if%20it%20is%20installed) хорошо описаны случаи, в которых это может произойти.